# adding BigNumbers with ethers

Tags: web3js, ethers.js

I am running tests and use ethers to format big numbers. I can't figure out how to add them.

For example, say I have two numbers I convert into 10 and 100 Finney:

```
      const x1 = utils.formatUnits("10000000000000000", "finney");
      const x2 = utils.formatUnits("100000000000000000", "finney");
```

If I console.log them, I see
console.log(x1) generates 10.0, while console.log(x2) generates 100.0. Interestingly,

`const y = x2 - x1;`

sets y to 90.0, while

`const y = x2 + x1;`

concatenates the strings, generating 100.010.0.

`const y = x2 - - x1;`

the above double negative correctly adds, generating 110.0! However, that's an ugly way to get what I want.

"x1.add(x2)", "utils.x1.add(x2)", etc., do not work. Can someone tell me how to add these numbers within my javascript file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ethers V5 the output is usually a object with two fields, `isBignumber` (boolean) and `_hex` field with a string representing the hexadecimal value of that number. So you need to pass inside `Number(bigNumber._hex)` in orther to make math. Ethers V6 would returning straight a `BigInt()`, big integers can do math with eachother but if you try to perform math between a big integer and a regular number it will also complain. Again you need to pass it inside `Number()`.

Comment: const x3 = Number(x1._hex) + Number(x2._hex)

does not work, so I am missing something

Interestingly, in my example where x2 = 100 finney and x1 = 10 finney, "x2 - x1" is correctly calculated as 90, while "x2 + x1" concatenates the numbers (100.010.0)

Comment: Can you console log both and share the output?

Comment: Only the output, not the code.

Comment: Just X1 and X2 variables.

Comment: x1 10.0 x2 100.0

Comment: String or number? Also what's the version of ethers?

Comment: ethers 5.7.2. Here x1 and x2 are strings, I think (I'm not sure because it does subtract them correctly, but doesn't add).

Comment: This works perfectly:

const x = "100.00"
const y = "10.0"

const res = Number(x) + Number(y)

console.log(res)

Comment: tx! I had Number(x._hex) earlier, which didn't work.